# Error: Use of 'self' in property access 'texture' before super.init initializes self

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and I am trying to learn swift by 
creating a simple card game. I typed exact same codes from a video.
But xcode shows the error "Use of 'self' in property access 'texture' before super.init initializes self"
Thanks for the help!

```
import SpriteKit

class Card: SKSpriteNode {
    var rank: Int
    var suit: String
    var imageNameUp: String
    var textureUp: SKTexture
    var textureDown: SKTexture

init(rank: Int, suit: String, faceUp: Bool){

    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
    self.imageNameUp = "\(suit)_\(rank)"
    self.textureUp = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNameUp)
    self.textureDown = SKTexture(imageNamed: "cardback")



    if faceUp {
      self.texture = textureUp  //error 
    } else {
      self.texture = textureDown  //error
    }

    super.init(texture: texture, color: nil, size: texture!.size())  //error causes when I try to unwrap size: texture!.size()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func flip(){
    self.texture = textureUp
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

The use of `self.texture = ...` is a call to the superclass SKSpriteNode's setter for [`texture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/texture) (`setTexture:` in Obj-C).

If you want to access superclass properties, you must do so ***after*** calling `super.init`.

In this case, I don't think you need to modify the superclass property at all, since the texture is being passed to `super.init`. You might use a local variable:

```
let texture = faceUp ? textureUp : textureDown
super.init(texture: texture, ...
```

I would also highly recommend using `let` instead of `var` for most of your properties. They should not need to change after `init`, and it's safer to use `let` to tell Swift that they *can't* change.